# Get files and folders names in a directory vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

So this code only gives me folder names. I need to get both folder and file names:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
  Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each Dir As String In Directory.GetDirectories("c:\")
      ListBox1.Items.Add(Dir)
    Next
  End Sub
End Class
```

I only get folders names as shown below:

```
c:\$Recycle.Bin
c:\Boot
c:\Config.Msi
c:\Desktop
c:\Documents and Settings
c:\Program Files
c:\Program Files (x86)
c:\ProgramData
c:\System Volume Information
c:\Users
c:\Windows
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to execute just one loop then you could use the class DirectoryInfo and its `EnumerateFileSystemInfos` method

```
Sub Main

    Dim di = new DirectoryInfo("D:\temp")
    for each fi in di.EnumerateFileSystemInfos()
        if (fi.Attributes & FileAttributes.Directory) = FileAttributes.Directory Then
            Console.WriteLine(fi.FullName + " is a directory")
        else
            Console.WriteLine(fi.FullName + " is a file")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The `EnumerateFileSystemInfo` method allows to start the enumeration of files and directory without loading the whole set of files and directories in memory. So, if you have many files and directories this approach could be more efficient

For the sake of the argument, I should also mention the method `Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries`
This method doesn't build a `DirectoryInfo` object so it is faster, but, of course, you can't easily distinguish if one of the returned strings is a File or a Directory

```
For each name in Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries("D:\temp")
   Console.WriteLine(name)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

to get files you have to use `Directory.GetFiles("C:\")`

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For Each Dir As String In Directory.GetDirectories("c:\")
            ListBox1.Items.Add(Dir)
        Next
        For Each Dir As String In Directory.GetFiles("c:\")
            ListBox1.Items.Add(Dir)
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: how can i get both files and folders name ?

Comment: i have extended my answer.